# What is the difference in the error handling of the send / sendto / recv / recvfrom functions?

Tags: sockets, tcp, udp

What is the difference in the error handling of the send / sendto / recv / recvfrom functions for sockets in blocking and nonblocking mode?

Answer (score 2):

Only that in non-blocking mode you can get EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK.